# how to fix filenames with dash or space

Tags: scripts, paths, source-code, zenity

I created a bash file, but when I run it to those files (or folders) which they have "space" or "-", my command doesn’t work! how to fix this problem.

```
   #!/bin/bash
    dpi=$(zenity --entry --text "DPI" --entry-text "72")
    width=$(zenity --entry --text "Width (feet)")
    height=$(zenity --entry --text "Height (feet)")
    w=$(echo "scale=2;($width*12*$dpi);"|bc)
    h=$(echo "scale=2;($height*12*$dpi);"|bc)
    g="$w""x""$h"
    FILES=($(zenity --file-selection --multiple --file-filter=""*.jpg" "*.JPG" "*.jpeg" "*.png" "*.PNG"" --title "Pick a file"))
   for file in "$FILES"
     do
       convert -units PixelsPerInch -density "$dpi"x"$dpi" -geometry "$g"! -quality 100 "$file" "$file"."JPG"

     done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes around variables to prevent word splitting.

You can do:

```
for file in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    if [[ $file == /* ]] && [[ -f $file ]]; then
       convert -units PixelsPerInch -density "${dpi}"x"$dpi" \
                      -geometry "$g"! -quality 100 "$file" "$file"."JPG"
    fi
done
```

Note that you don't need to quote variables inside `[[` as it is a shell keyword.

Also you should use double quotes around command substitution `$()` as they also suffer from word splitting.

Comment: not success yet

Comment: @Deniz Where is it failing? can you give a specific example?

Comment: after putting "" for $file or other variables, it can not find pictures, for example if the name of picture is : "A-B.jpg" it looks for A.jpg and B.jpg and says can not find it!

Comment: @Deniz thats because you have set `iFS` to `-` and the file names are presplitted and i guess thats what you want as you have explicitly set it ...quoting will prevent after-splitting..

Comment: my command works now, but if there is "space" character in folder names, it doesnot work!

Comment: @Deniz If you wanna match folder names literally you can use single/double quotes e.g. `'folder with spaces'/*.jpg`

Comment: @Deniz If my answer helped you, please select it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..if not, let me know the details....

Comment: if there is "space" character in file name or file path..command not work!...can you explain more how to fix this problem? what do you mean by using single/double quotes e.g. 'folder with spaces'/*.jpg

Comment: My problem solved by adding this command:IFS="$(printf '\n\t')"

Comment: @Deniz Then you can just do `IFS=$'\t'$'\n'`